# React state not updating correctly timing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The problem I am facing is that the state variable "rdata" is not being properly updated, or that there is a timing issue with when the state is updated and when the component is rendered In my code.

```
import './style/record.css'
import Menu from "./menu"
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
const Record=()=>
{
    const [rdate,setrdate] = useState({list:'',notes:''})
    const [rdata,setrdata] = useState([])

    const rdates = (e) =>
    {
         setrdate({list:e.target.value+'h',notes:e.target.value})
    }
    const rclick = () =>
    {
        if(rdate.list && rdate.notes)
        {
            const l = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(rdate.list))
            const n = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(rdate.notes))
            const arr = l.concat(n);
            setrdata(arr)
        } 
        
    }
    
    return(
        <div className="cmain">
           <div>
            <Menu/>
           </div>
           <div className='rcont'>
            <label style={{marginRight:'1em'}}>Enter The date</label>
            <input type="date" onChange={rdates} ></input> 
            <button type='submit' onClick={rclick}>click</button>
           </div>
           <div className='rdata'>
                {
                    (rdata.length>0) ?
                    
                <div className=''>
 
                    {rdata.map((ele,ind) => {
                    return(
                        <>
                        <div key={ind}>
                            {
                                console.log("outside",ele[0]?.title)
                            }
                    
                        <h2>description</h2>
                            
                        <h2>Notes</h2>
                            
                        </div>
                        </>
                    )}
                    )}
                </div>
                :<div> <h2>Enter a Date in Month/date/year</h2> </div>
                }
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Record
```

I have used the optional chaining operator "?."  to prevent any errors that may occur when the state variable is not yet updated but is still not working as expected. If I don't use optional chaining error is caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') and if is use optional chaining it is undefined. I am not sure why the state variable is not being updated properly, or if there is a problem with the optional chaining operator "?." that I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `rclick` is trying to access elements in localStorage before they are set. Where are you setting items in localStorage?

Comment: rclick is trying to access elements when on click

Comment: Yes, but if they are never set there is nothing to get so the `concat` fails

Comment: try this: `setrdata(prev => [...prev, ...arr])`

Comment: yes, I have the same doubts so I did console.log arr and it works inside the click function           console.log(arr)         output (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: setrdata(prev => [...prev, ...arr])  undefined

Comment: You'll need to post where you are setting and what you are expecting out of it. The code as posted just errors on getting localStorage items that don't exist.